# Validate SharePoint date time control

Tags: date-time

I have two fields; one is normal text box used to generate system current date and the another field is `<sharepoint :datetime control >`

I need to validate this two: the date selected in SharePoint datetime control is not less than the date generated in text box.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2):

You can go to

`List Settings -> Validation Settings`

Mention there the validation you want, something like

```
[X_Date] > [Created]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Asp:CompareValidator object instead of javascript. See sample code below

```
<SharePoint:DateTimeControl runat="server" ID="txtFrom" DateOnly="false" />
<SharePoint:DateTimeControl runat="server" ID="txtEnd" DateOnly="false" />
<asp:CompareValidator ID="cv" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="red" Type="Date" Operator="GreaterThanEqual" ControlToCompare="txtFrom$txtFromDate" ControlToValidate="txtEnd$txtEndDate"><img src="/_layouts/images/info16by16.gif"/> End Date should be more than Start Date</asp:CompareValidator>
```

Hope this helps you.